# SQL query does not return the expected value. PHP - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$uid=intval($_GET['uid']); //98765432109876543  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE uid = $uid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Won't return any result, PHP is 64bit.

Below I put the executed commands from mysql client. uid field is BIGINT

```
Output from the mysql client:

mysql> SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;

| id | uid       | paid_date           |

| 1 | 98765432109876543 | 2015-09-20 12:56:47  |
```

--

```
Output from the mysql client: 

mysql> SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE uid=98765432109876543 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So my question is, what is the reason  I cannot retrieve the expected value from the first sql query?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = $uid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; i think this would work. Is there any field named uid ?

Comment: @raveenanigam Yes there is, when I test it with shorter digit integer number it works, however I need it to work with 17 digit int.

Comment: check for int size ?

Comment: @raveenanigam Returns 8, so it is 64bit.

Comment: Put `var_dump($sql);` or `var_export($sql);` under the line `$sql = ...`. Then use a mysql client and paste the result in there. MySQL will then tell you what the problem is. Google "how to use the mysql command line client" or something.

Comment: @Beetle952580 I'll try and let you know.

Comment: @Beetle952580 mysql> SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE uid =98765432109876543 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @FiatPax what is the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE accounts \G` please? Update your question with the result of this query.

Comment: @Beetle952580 Changing the BIGINT to BIGINT UNSIGNED has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've executed your quires, just worked fine for me. You need to update your `table schema`.

I've tested with some thing like these.

First, I've create a `table` with `uid` as `VARCHAR(50)`, and it returned fine results.

Check this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f484/3).

but what if you want `uid` as `INT`? you can't use `INT` to store more than 10 or 11 char long string(integer) because it ranges from `-2147483648` to `2147483647` and for `UNSIGNED INT` ranging from `0` to `4294967295`.

So you've to use `BIGINT` instead, it ranges from `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`. Check this [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ce12/1).

I assume that `uid` will never have value in -ve, so use `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, it ranges from `0` to `18446744073709551615` and that will also work for you.

Check this [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd8b6/1)

[To read more about limitations/ranges, please look here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Changing it to BIGINT UNSIGNED fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think so there is no field in the database table accounts with uid that's why first query doesn't work.Use this query for getting proper results.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = $uid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: There is a field "uid" however uids have to be 17 digits long, and id field is just classic primary id field. Every person has a unique uid so uid is the only way to check for them hence that's why I can't use id instead of uid.